# GNOME freezes/crashes with AMD

Tags: amd-graphics

Random Freezes and Crashes on Ubuntu Jammy with AMD

```
➜  optiontrader git:(main) ✗ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
➜  optiontrader git:(main) ✗ uname -a
Linux lahaina 5.19.5-051905-generic #202208291036 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Aug 29 10:47:31 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
➜  optiontrader git:(main) ✗ 


Oct 18 09:57:35 lahaina kernel: amdgpu 0000:2f:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub] page fault (src_id:0 ring:24 vmid:2 pasid:32769, for process Xwayland pid 1331184 thread Xwayland:cs0 pid 1331213)
Oct 18 09:57:35 lahaina kernel: amdgpu 0000:2f:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x000080051441e000 from client 0x1b (UTCL2)
Oct 18 09:57:35 lahaina kernel: amdgpu 0000:2f:00.0: amdgpu: GCVM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00201031
Oct 18 09:57:35 lahaina kernel: amdgpu 0000:2f:00.0: amdgpu:          Faulty UTCL2 client ID: TCP (0x8)
Oct 18 09:57:35 lahaina kernel: amdgpu 0000:2f:00.0: amdgpu:          MORE_FAULTS: 0x1
Oct 18 09:57:35 lahaina kernel: amdgpu 0000:2f:00.0: amdgpu:          WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Oct 18 09:57:35 lahaina kernel: amdgpu 0000:2f:00.0: amdgpu:          PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x3
Oct 18 09:57:35 lahaina kernel: amdgpu 0000:2f:00.0: amdgpu:          MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Oct 18 09:57:35 lahaina kernel: amdgpu 0000:2f:00.0: amdgpu:          RW: 0x0
Oct 18 09:57:35 lahaina kernel: amdgpu 0000:2f:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub] page fault (src_id:0 ring:24 vmid:2 pasid:32769, for process Xwayland pid 1331184 thread Xwayland:cs0 pid 1331213)
Oct 18 09:57:35 lahaina kernel: amdgpu 0000:2f:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x0000800514260000 from client 0x1b (UTCL2)
Oct 18 09:57:35 lahaina kernel: amdgpu 0000:2f:00.0: amdgpu: GCVM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00000000
Oct 18 09:57:35 lahaina kernel: amdgpu 0000:2f:00.0: amdgpu:          Faulty UTCL2 client ID: CB/DB (0x0)
Oct 18 09:57:35 lahaina kernel: amdgpu 0000:2f:00.0: amdgpu:          MORE_FAULTS: 0x0
Oct 18 09:57:35 lahaina kernel: amdgpu 0000:2f:00.0: amdgpu:          WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Oct 18 09:57:35 lahaina kernel: amdgpu 0000:2f:00.0: amdgpu:          PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x0
Oct 18 09:57:35 lahaina kernel: amdgpu 0000:2f:00.0: amdgpu:          MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Oct 18 09:57:35 lahaina kernel: amdgpu 0000:2f:00.0: amdgpu:          RW: 0x0
Oct 18 09:57:35 lahaina kernel: amdgpu 0000:2f:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub] page fault (src_id:0 ring:24 vmid:2 pasid:32769, for process Xwayland pid 1331184 thread Xwayland:cs0 pid 1331213)
Oct 18 09:57:35 lahaina kernel: amdgpu 0000:2f:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x000080051442a000 from client 0x1b (UTCL2)
Oct 18 09:57:35 lahaina kernel: amdgpu 0000:2f:00.0: amdgpu: GCVM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00000000
Oct 18 09:57:35 lahaina kernel: amdgpu 0000:2f:00.0: amdgpu:          Faulty UTCL2 client ID: CB/DB (0x0)
Oct 18 09:57:35 lahaina kernel: amdgpu 0000:2f:00.0: amdgpu:          MORE_FAULTS: 0x0
Oct 18 09:57:35 lahaina kernel: amdgpu 0000:2f:00.0: amdgpu:          WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Oct 18 09:57:35 lahaina kernel: amdgpu 0000:2f:00.0: amdgpu:          PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x0
Oct 18 09:57:35 lahaina kernel: amdgpu 0000:2f:00.0: amdgpu:          MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Oct 18 09:57:35 lahaina kernel: amdgpu 0000:2f:00.0: amdgpu:          RW: 0x0
Oct 18 09:57:35 lahaina kernel: amdgpu 0000:2f:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub] page fault (src_id:0 ring:24 vmid:2 pasid:32769, for process Xwayland pid 1331184 thread Xwayland:cs0 pid 1331213)
Oct 18 09:57:35 lahaina kernel: amdgpu 0000:2f:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x0000800514434000 from client 0x1b (UTCL2)
Oct 18 09:57:35 lahaina kernel: amdgpu 0000:2f:00.0: amdgpu: GCVM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00000000
Oct 18 09:57:35 lahaina kernel: amdgpu 0000:2f:00.0: amdgpu:          Faulty UTCL2 client ID: CB/DB (0x0)
Oct 18 09:57:35 lahaina kernel: amdgpu 0000:2f:00.0: amdgpu:          MORE_FAULTS: 0x0
Oct 18 09:57:35 lahaina kernel: amdgpu 0000:2f:00.0: amdgpu:          WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Oct 18 09:57:35 lahaina kernel: amdgpu 0000:2f:00.0: amdgpu:          PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x0
```

Comment: Perhaps you could help us help you by offering some details about your hardware? AMD has made a lot of stuff since 1969 …

Comment: GPU is a Radeon 6600XT